# Elegant way to provide optional synchronous methods in an api?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I wrote a security Web API and all of the controller-level methods are async. My thought was that downstream clients could simply "await" the methods for synchronous handling as needed.

However, I've encountered a scenario where `AuthorizationAttribute` in ASP.NET MVC (pre-core) doesn't support async method hooks. So I need the ability to provide an optional synchronous version of some of these methods.

What would be an elegant way to do this? For example, let's say that I currently have the following route defined to get a user:

```
api/v1/users/{userGuid}
```

And this is the method signature:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserAsync(Guid id, [FromUri] string expand=null)
```

How could I update my API to provide a synchronous version of this method? It seems like I would need to update the uri to accommodate this like:

```
api/v1/users/{userGuid}/synchronous
```

Otherwise, how else would I be able to identify and handle a request for a synchronous version of a particular API method?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about what `async` controller methods really are. `async` and `await` do not affect the API itself, only the implementation.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserAsync(Guid id, [FromUri] string expand=null)
```

When you implement an action handler asynchronously, it means that the Web API framework can use the thread handling the request for other work while it's `await`ing the result of asynchronous operations (querying your database for example). This helps scale your service by increasing the request load it can handle on the same hardware.

**It does not have any impact on the caller**. To your HTTP client, the request looks the same whether it is handled synchronously or not. There's still an HTTP request coming in, and an HTTP response going back out over the same socket connection.

Now, if your client is using asynchronous calls to your API, it may relinquish the thread it is making the call on while your service is processing the request and producing a response. This may be useful if the client is an HTTP service itself, or an application with a message pump.

But in either case, it would call the API on the same endpoint whether the API is implemented using `async` methods or not.